# How to get tomorrow's, or the upcoming week's events, using query function?

Tags: date, google-sheets, timestamp

I have a list of events and their dates.   I can use the below formula to get today's (well sort-of as it is incorrectly filtering the date) information.

```
=query(A:B, "Select * Where toDate(A) = todate(now())")
```

Now I would like to show the events for the entire upcoming week but the below formula, which I though might work, doesn't

```
=query(A:B, "Select * Where toDate(A) = todate(now())+1")
```

Comment: I have it working with filter, but I am trying to get it to work using the Query function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With query:

```
=query(A:B,"Select * where A >= date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A<=date '"&text(today()+7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
```

but one of the `=` should be excluded, depending on which 7 days are required.

Comment: nice, I only needed to add toDate(A) around the reference to column A.

Comment: I was using the timestamp from a form, which I have found needs the toDate(A) around the column number to work as a date, because it includes the time.